# Groovy Reading and using data from .csv file in SoapUI

Tags: csv, groovy, soapui

I'm new to groovy script and what I'm trying to do is not working.
What I try to do is:

- Read a .csv file
- Add the data from from the .csv file to a variable that I can use in XML (e.g.

test.csv
name,age
Tester,20
Java,30

and use the Tester in a variable named name in the XML and 30 in a variable named 20)

Which software / jar files do I use:

- [OpenCSV v3.9](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/) jar file added to the SoapUI directory: bin/ext
- [GroovyCSV v1.1](https://github.com/xlson/groovycsv) jar file added to the SoapUI directory: bin/ext
- SoapUI 5.2.1.

I searched Google on how to do this and used the following code to try to get it working:

```
   @Grab('com.xlson.groovycsv:groovycsv:1.1')
import static com.xlson.groovycsv.CsvParser.parseCsv

def csv = '''Name,Lastname
Mark,Andersson
Pete,Hansen'''

def data = parseCsv(csv)
for(line in data) {
    println "$line.Name $line.Lastname"
}
```

This is what I used to see if everything is working but I am getting the following error code:

```
java.lang.noclassdeffounderror: org/apache/ivy/core/settings/Ivysettings
```

I searched Google for this but couldn't really find a good solution, please advise.

Comment: If you've put groovyCSV (and all dependant jars) in the classpath, you don't need the `@Grab`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Missing the dependency in the soapui's class path.

Just download the [`IvySetting`](http://www.findjar.com/jar/org/apache/ivy/ivy/2.1.0/ivy-2.1.0.jar.html) and copy it under SOAPUI_HOME/bin/ext directory and restart soapui, then retry.

EDIT: Based on comments.

- Got SoapUI 5.2
- Extracted & Copied `opencsv2.3.jar` from [this archive](https://sourceforge.net/projects/opencsv/files/opencsv/2.3/opencsv-2.3-src-with-libs.tar.gz) to SOAPUI_HOME/bin/ext
- Copied `groovycsv-1.1.jar` from [here](https://github.com/xlson/groovycsv/releases/download/releases%2F1.1/groovycsv-1.1.jar)
- Restart SOAPUI.

Able to run the below script:

```
import static com.xlson.groovycsv.CsvParser.parseCsv

def csv = '''Name,Lastname
Mark,Andersson
Pete,Hansen'''

def data = parseCsv(csv)
for(line in data) {
    println "$line.Name $line.Lastname"
}
```

`opencsv 3.9` has changed the packaging structure running into different issue. So, it would be better to stick to [`xlson`](https://github.com/xlson/groovycsv) documentation.

Comment: I've tried this, but still getting the exact same error. In the SOAPUI_HOME/bin/ext directory I got 3 jar files now: opencsv3.9, ivy2.4 and groovycsv1.1

Comment: Have you gone thru the readme of xlson? versions may be incompatible.